# Gitlab CI loops

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

I'm trying out a usecase where I need to create 4 different versions of the same file. I'm using loop in gitlab ci to accomplish this task. Assume that "sample.json" is the file whose four versions are desired to be created and the file is available.

Code Snippet inside the job -

```
script:
 - i=1
 - no_of_configs=4
 - while [ "$i" -le "$no_of_configs" ];
 -  do
 -    cp sample.json "sample_$i.json"
 -    i=$((i + 1))
 -  done
```

But I'm getting infinite looping when I execute the job. I echoed out value of i and no_of_configs inside the loop as well, value of i is getting incremented and value of no_of_configs is also constant i.e. 4. Seems that, I'm missing something in the loop condition. What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiline lists have newline removed and are then passed to the shell. So write it as-if it has no newlines - remember to put `;` in proper places.

```
script:
 - i=1
 - no_of_configs=4
 - while [ "$i" -le "$no_of_configs" ]; do
      cp sample.json "sample_$i.json";
      i=$((i + 1));
    done 

# an alternative:
 - seq 4 | xargs -I{} cp sample.json sample_{}.json
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the  infinite looping problem. However, I see **cp sample.json "sample_$i.json"** this statement each time outputs sample_$i.json. I want something like sample_1.json .. sample_4.json to be created as I loop through existing sample.json. Any solution for this?

Comment: Och, it does? It should have worked, as it is. I do not know where you "see" that, do `cp -v` or add `set -x` and confirm with what shell outputs, not what gitlab script parser outputs.